# how can I get the right index in react&antD

Tags: reactjs, antd

**AppUI.js**

```
class AppUI extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <List
                itemLayout="horizontal"
                dataSource={this.props.list}
                renderItem={(item, index) => (
                    <List.Item onClick={(index) => {
                        this.props.handleDelete(index)
                    }}>
                        {item.title}
                    </List.Item>
                )}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = store.getState();
    this.handleStore = this.handleStore.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    store.subscribe(this.handleStore);
}


render() {
    return (
        <AppUI
            handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
            list={this.state.list}
        />
    )
}



handleDelete(index) {
    const action = getDeleteListAction(index);
    store.dispatch(action);
}

handleStore() {
    this.setState(store.getState())

}
```

}

> my question is that how can I get the right index when I click each list
>   my question is that how can I get the right index when I click each list
>   my question is that how can I get the right index when I click each list

```
  renderItem={(item, index) => (
                        <List.Item onClick={(index) => {
                            this.props.handleDelete(index)
                        }}>
                            {item.title}
                        </List.Item>
                    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick handler needs a bit of tweaking, that param is actually the event, which is what you ended up passing into handleDelete. You want something like

```
renderItem={(item, index) => (
  <List.Item onClick={() => {
    this.props.handleDelete(index)
  }}>
    {item.title}
  </List.Item>
)}
```

As a side note, its probably better in the long run to pass the item itself and find by a ID or some sort of identifier

Comment: Oh thanks, you mean code should change like this
 renderItem={(item) => (
                        <List.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.props.handleDelete(item)
                        }}>
                            {item.title}
                        </List.Item>
                    )}

Comment: Yes, it will be easier to maintain in the future if you rely on finding the item instead of the index in the array. Feel free to use the index if you would like, its just a suggestion

Comment: hey dude, I have a question about my problem when I change my code like this 

`renderItem={(item) => (
                        <List.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.props.handleDelete(item)
                        }}>
                            {item.title}
                        </List.Item>
                    )}`
should I add key={item} into my code? I don't know why it couldn't work.

Comment: No your key cannot be an object. I would avoid using the index in this case because you are removing which changes the indexes. Do you have an id or something inside the item you can use?

Comment: `const defaultState = {

    inputValue: '',

    list: [
        {title: 'Math'},
        {title: 'Science'},
        {title: 'Psychology'}
    ]
};` 
like this

Comment: `renderItem={(item,index) => (
                    <List index={item.title} onClick={() => {
                        props.handleDelete(index)
                    }}>
                        {item.title}
                    </List>
                )}`should I write code like this?